# Measure of preimage of Jordan disk under entire map

Tags: cv.complex-variables, measure-theory, analytic-functions

Let $f\colon\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire map. For simplicity assume that $f$ is of finite type, i.e., it has finite set $S(f)$ of singular values. $S(f) \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a minimal (under inclusion) closed set such that $f\colon \mathbb{C} \setminus f^{-1}(S(f)) \to \mathbb{C} \setminus S(f)$ is a covering. For example, $f$ can be $\exp$ with $S(\exp) = \{0\}$ or $\cos$ with $S(\cos) = \{-1, 1\}$.

Take $U \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus S(f)$ be an closed Jordan disk. Let $V$ be its preimage under map $f$, i.e., $V = f^{-1}(U)$. My question is the following. Is it true that
$$
\lim_{r \to \infty}\frac{\mu(V \cap B(0, r))}{\mu (B(0, r))} = 0,
$$
where $B(0,r) = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < r\}$ and $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. At least, it is true for $\exp$ and $\cos$ and I am curious whether it can be extended for a larger class of maps.

P.S. Also, it is interesting whether this holds for $U$ containing at most 1 critical value of $f$, that is not an asymptotic one.

Answer (score 1):

What you say is not correct, even for $e^z$. The preimage of the open disk
$\{z:|z-1|<1\}$ under $e^z$ does not satisfy your condition. However, if you consider a closed disk which does not contain singular values, the question makes sense (I think it is unsolved).

Concerning your second question (in P. S. about the disc containing one non-asymptotic singular value) this was disproved by Ch. Bishop

Bishop, Christopher J.
Constructing entire functions by quasiconformal folding.
Acta Math. 214 (2015), no. 1, 1–60.